# Append a text file using C#

Tags: c#

I have write the following C# code to append a file. I need to store each data in a new line. But after entering the data I can see them in a single line.

How can I modify my code to get one input in one line.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

      Console.WriteLine("Please enter the question:");
      string question = Console.ReadLine();
      File.AppendAllText("question.txt", question);
      File.AppendAllText("question.txt", "\n");
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter the term to solve");
      string term = Console.ReadLine();
      File.AppendAllText("question.txt", term);
}
```

Required output -

```
x+2=10

x
```

Output I got -

```
x+2=10x
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `+ Environment.NewLine` after `term`. You can concat string with `+`(plus) "mystring" + " another String" + " my last string" = "mystring another String my last string".

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

      Console.WriteLine("Please enter the question:");
      string question = Console.ReadLine();
      File.AppendAllText("question.txt", question);
      File.AppendAllText("question.txt", "\n");
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter the term to solve");
      string term = Console.ReadLine();
      File.AppendAllText("question.txt", term + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not to build a string and write it at once?

```
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter the question:");
  string question = Console.ReadLine();

  Console.WriteLine("Please enter the term to solve");

  question += Environment.NewLine + Console.ReadLine();
  File.WriteAllText("question.txt", question );
```

Anyway, as C# application might be cross platform, `/n` is not always a character for the new line, that is why it is better to use `Environment.NewLine` instead

Answer (score 1):

The text viewer you are viewing the resulting file with likely expects a "carriage return"(\r) character with each "newline"(\n) character.  Try changing the following line:

```
File.AppendAllText("question.txt", "\n");
```

To this:

```
File.AppendAllText("question.txt", "\r\n");
```